Multiprocessing issue: DL trained model fails to use GPU, now raising UnpicklingError
I'm using a pretrained image (video) denoising DL model, DeepCAD-RT (https://github.com/cabooster/DeepCAD-RT). It's supposed to be using GPU, instead it's raising these issues (ArrayMemoryError the first time I tried to run it, RuntimeError the second, Unpickling the third) and I can see that it's mostly using memory. It seems I have two problems: it's not using GPU (specifically it needs to use cuda) like it should, and multiprocessing issues. How do I fix it?
First time:
To: C:\Users\User1\DeepCAD-RT\DeepCAD_RT_pytorch\pth\fish_localbrain_best_model_demo\best_model.yaml
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 337/337 [00:00<?, ?B/s]
Testing parameters ----->
{'overlap_factor': 0.6, 'datasets_path': 'datasets/fish_localbrain_demo', 'fmap': 16, 'output_dir': './results', 'pth_dir': './pth', 'batch_size': 1, 'patch_t': 150, 'patch_x': 150, 'patch_y': 150, 'gap_y': 60, 'gap_x': 60, 'gap_t': 60, 'GPU': '0', 'ngpu': 1, 'num_workers': 4, 'scale_factor': 1, 'test_datasize': 100000, 'denoise_model': 'fish_localbrain_best_model_demo', 'visualize_images_per_epoch': False, 'colab_display': False, 'result_display': ''}
Stacks for processing ----->
Total stack number ----->  1
fish_localbrain.tif
Using 1 GPU(s) for testing ----->
Testing the last model by default:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User1\DeepCAD-RT\DeepCAD_RT_pytorch\demo_test_pipeline.py", line 71, in <module>
    tc.run()
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\site-packages\deepcad\test_collection.py", line 76, in run
    self.test()
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\site-packages\deepcad\test_collection.py", line 231, in test
    input_img = np.zeros(noise_img.shape)
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 12.5 GiB for an array with shape (6955, 492, 492) and data type float64

Second time (without changing anything):
[...]
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Third time (after keyboard interrupt and adding this to my code (I put everything inside the if below freeze support, and imported multiprocessing and freeze_support from multiprocessing)):
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()


(deepcadrt) C:\Users\User1\DeepCAD-RT\DeepCAD_RT_pytorch>python demo_test_pipeline.py
Testing parameters ----->
{'overlap_factor': 0.6, 'datasets_path': 'datasets/fish_localbrain_demo', 'fmap': 16, 'output_dir': './results', 'pth_dir': './pth', 'batch_size': 1, 'patch_t': 150, 'patch_x': 150, 'patch_y': 150, 'gap_y': 60, 'gap_x': 60, 'gap_t': 60, 'GPU': '0', 'ngpu': 1, 'num_workers': 4, 'scale_factor': 1, 'test_datasize': 100000, 'denoise_model': 'fish_localbrain_best_model_demo', 'visualize_images_per_epoch': False, 'colab_display': False, 'result_display': ''}
Stacks for processing ----->
Total stack number ----->  1
fish_localbrain.tif
Using 1 GPU(s) for testing ----->
Testing the last model by default:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User1\DeepCAD-RT\DeepCAD_RT_pytorch\demo_test_pipeline.py", line 75, in <module>
    tc.run()
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\site-packages\deepcad\test_collection.py", line 76, in run
    self.test()
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\site-packages\deepcad\test_collection.py", line 236, in test
    for iteration, (noise_patch, single_coordinate) in enumerate(testloader):
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 355, in __iter__
    return self._get_iterator()
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 301, in _get_iterator
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 914, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniconda3\envs\deepcadrt\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated

For more information, I'm using Windows, which is the only requirement that I'm not satisfying of the ones they list. My system has two GPUs, one Intel and the other NVIDIA with CUDA 11.1. It seems to be detecting it since it is using it a little bit when I check the processes (0.7%), but it's mainly using RAM (40%).
Here is the code in the demo_train_pipeline.py file after the multiprocessing modification:
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
from deepcad.test_collection import testing_class
from deepcad.movie_display import display
from deepcad.utils import get_first_filename,download_demo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    # %% Select file(s) to be processed (download if not present)
    download_demo_file = True
    if download_demo_file:
        file_name= 'fish_localbrain' # select the demo file you want to test (e.g. 'ATP_3D', 'fish_localbrain', 'NP_3D', ...)
        datasets_path, denoise_model = download_demo(download_filename=file_name)
    else:
        datasets_path = 'datasets/fish_localbrain_demo'  # folder containing tif files for testing
        denoise_model = 'fish_localbrain_best_model_demo'  # A folder containing pth models to be tested

    # %% First setup some parameters for testing
    test_datasize = 100000                # the number of frames to be tested (test all frames if the number exceeds the total number of frames in a .tif file)
    GPU = '0'                             # the index of GPU you will use for computation (e.g. '0', '0,1', '0,1,2')
    patch_xy = 150                        # the width and height of 3D patches
    patch_t = 150                         # the time dimension of 3D patches
    overlap_factor = 0.6                  # the overlap factor between two adjacent patches. 
                                        # Since the receptive field of 3D-Unet is ~90, seamless stitching requires an overlap (patch_xyt*overlap_factor）of at least 90 pixels.
    num_workers = 4                       # if you use Windows system, set this to 0.

    # %% Setup some parameters for result visualization during testing period (optional)
    visualize_images_per_epoch = False  # choose whether to display inference performance after each epoch

    # %% Play the demo noise movie (optional)
    # playing the first noise movie using opencv.
    display_images = False

    if display_images:
        display_filename = get_first_filename(datasets_path)
        print('\033[1;31mDisplaying the first raw file -----> \033[0m')
        print(display_filename)
        display_length = 500  # the frames number of the noise movie
        # normalize the image and display
        display(display_filename, display_length=display_length, norm_min_percent=0.5, norm_max_percent=99.8)

    test_dict = {
        # dataset dependent parameters
        'patch_x': patch_xy,
        'patch_y': patch_xy,
        'patch_t': patch_t,
        'overlap_factor':overlap_factor,
        'scale_factor': 1,                   # the factor for image intensity scaling
        'test_datasize': test_datasize,
        'datasets_path': datasets_path,
        'pth_dir': './pth',                 # pth file root path
        'denoise_model' : denoise_model,
        'output_dir' : './results',         # result file root path
        # network related parameters
        'fmap': 16,                          # the number of feature maps
        'GPU': GPU,
        'num_workers': num_workers,
        'visualize_images_per_epoch': visualize_images_per_epoch
    }
    # %%% Testing preparation
    # first we create a testing class object with the specified parameters
    tc = testing_class(test_dict)
    # start the testing process
    tc.run()


I'm not entirely sure what is going on so my question is just - how do I fix these issues and make it work?
Thanks in advance.
